# ClickOnce update with Apache server

Tags: c#, apache, .htaccess, clickonce

I have been working on a C# application which needs bug fixes and updates once i deliver it to clients. I am currently trying clickOnce method of microsoft to provide updates.

For that i need to publish my application to server with frontpage server extension (If i am not wrong!). We are using windows server 2008 enabled machine, with Apache running, i googled regarding "Publish c sharp application on Apache server" and i found [this workaround.](http://www.devprise.com/2006/12/10/publishing-a-net-clickonce-application-to-a-linux-apache-server/)

It edits `.htaccess` file to allow access to VS to publish application. But it doesn't seem working. I guess the page is out dated, written in 2006.

So my questions are:

1. How do i publish c sharp app on apache box?
2. How do we publish app? Using VS or any other method?

Comment: You should be able to just place whatever files the publish action created into a folder mapping to the url given when publishing the file. Clickonce is very simple. Once the user can 'download' the files you should be good to go.

Comment: i placed all files generated by 'publish' in the folder specified by url. i even changed the version in manifest file, but app doesn't prompt for available update. I doubt its not checking the url.

I changed project properties to check updates before starting app, specifying the check url. but no luck!

Comment: If you install just published app on a clean machine will it be the newest version? And just after that if you start previous version installed on another machine, will it update itsef? If answers is yes and no, then check that you selected right update strategy *Before the application starts*.

Comment: when i create setup, it detects existing version and says it will upgrade to newer version, but it doesn't seems to work. I tried changing version numbers in manifest file, used major and minor upgrades, but no luck.

Comment: Before deploying to Apache, try publishing to a file share on a server (or even on your dev machine), install on a test machine (or even your dev machine), publish an update, and check the client updates.  If that isn't working then you will know it is a general click-once problem, if that works, you know it is something to do with hosting it via a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest and payload (files) just need to be generated and then copied en masse to your server, it doesn't have to be a Windows machine.

Publish to a local folder/share and then **replace** the entire ClickOnce folder so that the code security values remain intact.  I'd suggest you always rename your current folder and then copy your latest bits into a "new" folder that is your install location.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to give updates with this workaround (i dont know how feasible is this! Need inputs!)

I used database to track version numbers and (link for) latest copy of software. Then i check for updates on startup. If new update is available it downloads exe (in app itself), closes app and run the setup.

I am using install-shield to generate setup. But when i run setup in machine which is already having older version of software, it doesn't update it, even though it displays its updating.

I know visual studio also provides option to create installation, but it isn't working either!